# Debugging save() returning false CakePHP 3.0

Tags: debugging, cakephp, save, cakephp-3.0

I have some code which has broken somewhere along the way and I'm having trouble debugging it.

This is a simplified version of it.

```
$data = $this->request->data;

$form = $this->Forms->get($data['id'], [
    'contain' => ['FieldsForms' => ['data']
    ]
]);

$form = $this->Forms->patchEntity($form, $data,
    ['associated' => [
        'FieldsForms.Data',

    ]
]);

if ($this->Forms->save($form)) {
    // sunshine and rainbows
} else {
    // wailing and gnashing of teeth
}
```

I'm left wailing and gnashing teeth without any errors, as far as I can see if I debug the $data it looks like it's ok (though since it's fairly long and contains a bunch of UUIDs it's possible I'm missing something).

Validation errors is empty.

The save is returning false - any suggestions on how to debug this might save what sanity I have left.

Thanks!

Comment: When you are saying "_Validation errors is empty_", how do you check that? _After_ saving so that possible table rule errors are included?

Comment: The view is rendered and using debug kit it shows validation for 'form' as empty

Comment: Then I'd suggest digging into the CakePHP core source to debug the control flow that originates from the `Table::save()` call.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the data, as expected but couldn't see immediately because the save was returning false and the data was quite large.

I first made a subset of the problem data which displayed the same behaviour then, following ndm's suggestion, changed the ORM/Table.php code for the save function as follows to be able to see where the problem was:

```
// $entity->errors() is deprecated as of CakePHP 3.7
// $entity->getErrors() should be used in later versions
$x = $entity->errors();
if ($x) {
    debug($entity);
    debug($x);
    return false;
}
```

So that I could see what was going on and went on to fix the data.

Comment: Rich - this is brilliant. Works like a charm. Is there any way to implement this by overriding the Table class in your app code, instead of modifying the core? Thank you.

Comment: $entity->getErrors() should be used instead of $entity->errors() in CakePHP 3.7 and higher.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if the earlier answer is based on an older version, but in the latest cakephp version (3.4) you can retrieve the errors directly from the $entity within the controller. The errors array contains each entity field that failed, with a child array of failed validations.

```
<?php
// In Articles Controller
...

public function add(){
...
  if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('The Article has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
  } else {
    Log::Debug($article->errors());
  }
```

Comment: Using cakephp 3.3.* helped a lot thanks one up arrow from me!

Comment: For me, the following worked well: **}else{debug($item->errors());}** Though I wonder why debug the $item value doesn't display the errors part of the $item object by default. It would be easier if by simply '(trivial debugging the manipulated value ($item in my case, or $article here up) one could directly see those eventual errors .

Answer (score 0):

Instead modify the core Cake code you can do this:

```
if ($this->Forms->save($form)) {
    // sunshine and rainbows
} else {
    //you know now what fail
    $andTheErrorsAre = $entity->getErrors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3.4.*

Try this code:

```
if (!$this->Forms->save($form)) {
    $this->log($form->getErrors(),'error');
}
```

Read more about logs here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#using-the-filelog-adapter